# Python => ValueError: unsupported format character 'Y' (0x59)

Tags: python, mysql

I don't understand the ValueError with Y. I escape with %...

```
table = town+"_history"
db.execute("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(snapdate,'%%Y-%%m-%%d') AS date, SUM( population ) AS accountpopulation, count( blockid ) AS number_block FROM %s WHERE blockid =%%s GROUP BY snapdate ORDER BY snapdate DESC LIMIT 7" % table, (blockid))
```

Comment: Can you give some more info?  What is in table?  What is passed to the resulting format string (i.e. what is given to the string that has the "%Y"?

Comment: @SethMMorton: the MySQL `DATE_FORMAT()` function expects a formatting string that uses `%Y`, etc. formatting codes. But so does the Python string formatting operation using the `%` operator, and so does the MySQL database that supports `%s` SQL parameters *by using string formatting with the `%` operator*.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You escape the `%%` but then use the string as a formatter *first*:

```
"...." % table,
```

that returns a new string with the `%%` escaped percentages replaced by single `%` characters. The MySQL database adapter (ab)uses string formatting with `%` *too*, so it'll take that output and expect to be able to fill `%s` slots with escaped SQL literals. It is there that your `'%Y-%m-%d'` part of the SQL statement is being interpreted again as a string format and the error is thrown.

The solution is to either double the doubling:

```
db.execute("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(snapdate,'%%%%Y-%%%%m-%%%%d') AS date, SUM( population ) AS accountpopulation, count( blockid ) AS number_block FROM %s WHERE blockid = %%s GROUP BY snapdate ORDER BY snapdate DESC LIMIT 7" % table, (blockid,))
```

or use `str.format()` instead and avoid having to doubly-escape:

```
db.execute("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(snapdate,'%%Y-%%m-%%d') AS date, SUM( population ) AS accountpopulation, count( blockid ) AS number_block FROM {0} WHERE blockid = %s GROUP BY snapdate ORDER BY snapdate DESC LIMIT 7".format(table), (blockid,))
```

Here `{0}` is replaced by the table name and the `%%` escapes are left untouched; the database adapter will use the `%s` slot to fill in the `blockid` parameter and return a SQL statement with the `%%` escapes turned into single `%` characters.

Comment: The first solution => TypeError: Decimal('220') is not JSON serializable. The secondone ==> ValueError: zero length field name in format.

Comment: @OlZ: What is turning this into JSON? What is the traceback you get? And if you are using Python 2.6, you need to use `{0}` as the field placeholder.

Comment: @OlZ: and the first error sounds like the database query *succeeded* but that you are then trying to serialize byte data using JSON. That'd be a *new* problem instead; this code worked.

Comment: I use a python framework => bottle.py Yes i'm using Python 2.6

Comment: If all you are getting now is the `TypeError: Decimal('220') is not JSON serializable.` error then that is beyond the scope of where I can help you; you solved the database problem now and found a new one, but you'll have to ask a new question about that. Include code and a *full* traceback (not just the exception message at the end).

Comment: Thanks Martijn. But you're right and no.. How i can have a decimal on a date ?????

Comment: @OlZ: I think this question may help: [Python MySQLdb returns datetime.time and decimal](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7483363)

Answer (score 4):

Finally, @Martijn Pieters you are completely right. And thank you for your useful answer. The other error comes from SUM and COUNT. Python sometimes runs in a crazy way when dealing with JSON. So the complete answer is:

```
db.execute("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(snapdate,'%%%%Y-%%%%m-%%%%d') AS date, CAST(SUM( population ) AS CHAR ) AS accountpopulation, CAST(count( blockid ) AS CHAR) AS number_block FROM %s WHERE blockid = %%s GROUP BY snapdate ORDER BY snapdate DESC LIMIT 7" % table, (blockid,))
```