# type "decimal" included in output

Tags: python, postgresql

When I run this code, I get results like:

```
(3205, Decimal('1.000'))(28802, Decimal('7.000'))(3106, Decimal('1.000'))(3173, Decimal('5.000')).
```

I don't want to see the "decimal" word included in the output, how do I avoid this?

```
cur.execute('SELECT tk_product_ord, SUM(tk_qty_ord) as qty_required '
        'FROM table1 WHERE tk_date = 15047 AND tk_prod_group = 11 '
        'GROUP BY tk_product_ord;')

answer = cur.fetchall()

file = open("test_data_output.txt")
with open("test_data_output.txt", "w") as line:
    for item in answer:
        line.write("%s\n" % str(item))
    file.close()
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483363/python-mysqldb-returns-datetime-date-and-decimal

Comment: FYI, the `file = open("test_data_output.txt")` and `file.close()` are redundant. The `with open("test_data_output.txt", "w") as line` is a context manager, it will automatically close `line`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `for item in answer:`, `item` is a `tuple`.  In Python, if the call `str` on a `tuple`, or another collection like a `list` or `dict`, the items in the collections are shown as their [repr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) rather than their [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str).

To get the output that you want, call `str` on each element of `item` and call [str.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) on the result:

```py
with open("test_data_output.txt", "w") as line:
    for item in answer:
        output = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in item])
        line.write("%s\n" % output)
```

The expression `[str(elem) for elem in item]` is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), a way of generating a list from an existing sequence object like a `list` or `tuple`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're using `str(item)`, which will include the Decimal type name in the `repr` call to those objects.

By converting the decimal to a float you will remove this:

Instead of `line.write("%s\n" % str(item))` you can do something like
`line.write(f"{item[0]}, {float(item[1])}")`